# how to convert a numeric value into eng.words e.g 10 to ten in sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to convert a numeric value into eng.words  e.g 10 to ten  in sql statement?

Comment: Roughly, what's the range of numbers you expect to have to deal with?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @INPUT int
SET @input = 1

SELECT CASE WHEN @INPUT = 1 THEN 'One' 
            WHEN @INPUT = 2 THEN 'Two'

etc...

            WHEN @INPUT = 10 THEN 'Ten'

END AS [Value]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Joe Celko](http://www.celko.com/) suggests [NUMTOWORDS](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qNXaiM_gNbYC&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=convert+a+numeric+value+into+eng.words+in+sql&source=bl&ots=TM5CH1HYvx&sig=8SNgr2EvdpTnCUfq9sHO5s9HkkU&hl=en&ei=iDrMSs7GONChjAegwMHoDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10#v=onepage&q=&f=false),one of the [implementations](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1064&lngWId=5)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a large number, then you are best off creating a lookup table to do this for you. For a small number Ralph's solution is more than adequate.

Another option is to use an algorithm in another tier to do this for you- like the one [discussed here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NumberToWords.aspx). You could even write a [stored procedure in C#](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/writing-clr-stored-procedures-in-charp-introduction-to-charp-part-1) if you wanted to.

Comment: Yep, I am assuming, simply from the phrasing of the question, a very small list of numbers